# MarkLogic xdmp.save never returning value or throwing error

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, marklogic

**Version:** MarkLogic 10.0-9

For context I am using the JavaScript version of the xdmp library.

I am using the built in xdmp library to add objects in S3. For saving and object we use `xdmp.save`, and for deleting we use `xdmp.filesystemFileDelete`. I am going to assume `xdmp.filesystemFileDelete` is deprecated. I no longer see this function in the documentation, but it's not very important since I am going to handle the object deletion on the AWS side going forward. This issue exists in both functions regardless.

As you can see from the logs below, the `xdmp.save` function is receiving a 403 Forbidden error. This makes sense. I accidentally tried to use the wrong S3 bucket. The problem is that the `xdmp.save` function never returned a value or threw any errors. The function kept running until MarkLogic killed the process after the timeout limit was reached. This had a knock on effect as the whole process queue was backed up waiting for this to finish.

It took about 37 seconds to give up on uploading the object in S3. The function ran for about 30 more seconds and never hit my trace (via `xdmp.trace`) log at the end of the script. It's like the `xdmp.save` function is stuck in an infinite loop.

```
2022-12-20 11:22:54.266 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 1 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:22:54.367 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 2 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:22:54.533 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 3 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:22:54.827 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 4 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:22:55.379 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 5 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:22:56.426 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 6 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:22:58.452 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 7 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:23:01.505 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 8 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:23:05.552 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 9 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:23:10.600 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 10 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:23:16.648 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 11 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:23:23.700 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 12 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
2022-12-20 11:23:31.729 Debug: Retrying S3Rep::PUT 4314 13 because SVC-S3ERR: S3 error: PUT 4314 https://[REDACTED].s3.amazonaws.com/[REDACTED].json 403 Forbidden Code=AccessDenied Message="Access Denied" RequestId=[REDACTED] HostId=[REDACTED]
```

Here is the code (this is very much a work in progress):

```
'use strict';
declareUpdate();

const config = require('/config/config.sjs');

xdmp.trace('export trace', 'Firing Trigger for export');
if (config.exportEnabled && uri) {
    const inputType = fn.substringBefore(fn.substringAfter(uri, '/data/'), '/');
    const document = cts.doc(uri);
    const mutableDocument = document.toObject();
    const key = `${config.s3ExportPath}/${inputType}-${mutableDocument.content.uuid}.json`;

    if(inputType === 'tasker' && mutableDocument && mutableDocument.workflowStatus === 'Draft') {
        xdmp.trace('export trace', 'Drafts are not exported.');
    } else {
      const permissions = xdmp.documentGetPermissions(uri);
      const exportedDocument = Object.assign(
          {}, 
          mutableDocument, 
          { 
              properties: {
                uri,
                type: inputType,
                permissions: permissions.map(permission => [xdmp.roleName(permission.roleId), permission.capability]),
                collections: xdmp.documentGetCollections(uri),
                exportDate: fn.currentDateTime()
            }
        });
      xdmp.trace('export trace', `Adding document with properties in S3: ${key}`);
      xdmp.save(key, exportedDocument, { outputEncoding: 'utf-8', mediaType: 'application/json' });
    }
} else {
  xdmp.trace('export trace', 'Either export is disabled, or uri is missing.');  
  xdmp.trace('export trace', `config.exportEnabled: ${config.exportEnabled}`);
  xdmp.trace('export trace', `uri: ${uri}`);
}

xdmp.trace('export trace', 'Fired Trigger for export');
```

I tried wrapping it in a try/catch block, but the function never returns anything or throws and error.

Is there a better way to save objects to S3 using MarkLogic?

Comment: NOTICE.txt in the MarkLogic distribution lists the use of "AWS SDK for Java". As I understand it, that API treats  403 as a retry-able status code. I believe that then it is subject to retry-count and backoff formulas. These can be environment variables etc.    It may be good to contact support at MarkLogic to see if there is a way to tune the AS API's underlying settings

Comment: So, you configured the wrong bucket and it wasn't working - but you expected to eventually get an exception thrown and it did not? When you have the correct S3 bucket specified, it does save as expected? You are just looking to have better error handling?

Comment: By the way, `xdmp.filesystemFileDelete()` is not deprecated. There is a bug filed to ensure that it's documented similar to `xdmp.filesystemDirectoryDelete`,  `xdmp.filesystemFile`, etc.

Comment: I did a quick test with an invalid S3 path: `xdmp:save("s3://invalid.s3.amazonaws.com/test.txt", text{"test"})` and saw that it retried 60 times before finally returning an error `[1.0-ml] SVC-S3ERR: xdmp:save("s3://invalid.s3.amazonaws.com/test.txt", text{"test"}) -- S3 error: Not able to get path for for host macpro-6232.marklogic.com curlCode: 6, Couldn't resolve host name %4 %5`

Comment: @MadsHansen It works as intended when I am using the correct bucket. I am looking for better error handling because it appears to tie up the main thread. Everything else gets backed up, until the function times out.

Comment: Gotcha, but it does eventually return an error, right? Just not very immediate - and that's the inconvenient part?

Comment: It does return an error eventually. The xdmp.save/filesystemFileDelete in our code is relatively low priority. The problem is, all the other queries seem to get backed up behind this when it takes a minute to timeout, including Q console queries. So, production queries related to searching, updating, creating docs, etc. are taking forever.